# Proper way to decorate async function

Tags: javascript, function, promise, decorator

I want to make a function decorator and measure async's function execution time, and return resolve or reject results as indented without decorating. Any clue how to achieve this? Most guides are about sync functions and are not touching the async world.

This is an example to illustrate the desired functionality

```
async exampleFunction () {
try{
  const response = await aPromise() // The goals is to measure this one with a decorator measure(aPromise) and dispatch actions if the fetching takes a long time
}
catch (err){
  // Do something with error
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*results as indented without decorating*"?

Comment: @Bergi I think "indented" was a typo for "intended"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Maybe, but still what are the intended results?

Comment: @Bergi I interpreted "the intended results" to be that whatever it originally fulfilled or rejected with, is propagated. Essentially hooking the "decorator" with a `finally` like in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a higher-order function that can measure the time it takes for the returned promise to settle either by fulfilling or rejecting:

```js
function measure(fn) {
  return async (...args) => {
    const begin = performance.now();
    try {
      return await fn(...args);
    } finally {
      const end = performance.now();
      console.log(`Execution time: ${end - begin}`);
    }
  };
}
```

Example usage:

```js
exampleFunction();

async function exampleFunction() {
  try {
    const value = await measure(defer)('foo', 1000);
    // where normally you'd write:
    // const value = await defer('foo', 1000);
    console.log(`Resolved with ${value}`);
  } catch (reason) {
    console.log(`Rejected with ${reason}`);
  }
}

function measure(fn) {
  return async (...args) => {
    const begin = performance.now();
    try {
      return await fn(...args);
    } finally {
      const end = performance.now();
      console.log(`Execution time: ${end - begin}`);
    }
  };
}

function defer(result, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const settle = Math.random() < 0.5 ? resolve : reject;
      settle(result);
    }, ms);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @patrick-roberts . Would be possible to avoid currying for example the part of  `measure(defer)('foo', 1000)` to become `measure(defer('foo', 1000))` ? Is there any constraint, or just a preference?

Comment: @konsalex sure, but I'd argue that's poorer design because at that point you're not measuring the entire lifetime of the promise (or at least not guaranteed to). That design would allow you to pass a promise that's been pending for some unknown amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
export function MeasureExecutionTime(target, propertyKey, descriptor)  {
  const fun = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = async function(...args) {
    const start = performance.now();
    const result = await fun.apply(target, args);
    const end = performance.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${end - start}`);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Typescript only, or works with vanilla js?

Comment: @Guerric P The new function you assign in your code is never returning the original value. you need something like `const result = await fun(...args)` and at the end `return result`

Comment: It's a stage 2 proposal for JavaScript https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators so it's still experimental, you should use TypeScript at the moment to implement this.

Comment: Yes @DavidB. good catch

Comment: I could be way off-base here but I don't think OP is referring to the stage 2 decorator proposal, I think they just mean a higher-order function.

Comment: well higher order functions obviously work but the `@MeasureExecutionTime` decorator syntax won't

Comment: Yeah but with this `MeasureExecutionTime` definition, it's not really clear as the answer stands how to actually use it without the decorator syntax.

Comment: Yes, this would work with Class' method, but with enclosed function inside class methods' wouldn't work if I get this right